# First four verses of each Vedas

Tags: vedas

What are the first four verses of each Veda. Please someone post the first four verses of each Vedas for daily ritual purposes

Comment: You can get Sanskrit text at [Vedic Reserve](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/).

Comment: First 4 mantras of each Veda or first mantra of each of the Vedas.. the later is important because those 4 are used in the Brahma Yajnam.. i assumed that you are asking for the later.. because u stated "for daily ritual purposes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the ritual called Brahma Yajna, which is to be performed on a daily basis, the first Mantras of each of the 4 Vedas are required to be recited.

**Rig Veda:**

> Agnimile purohitam yajnasya devamritvijam hotAtAm ratnadhatamam ||

(Rishi- Madhucchandah, Chandah- GAyatri, DevatA- Agni)

**Yajur Veda:**

> Ishe tvorjjetvA vAyavah stha devo vah savitA prAparyatu sreshthatamAya
>   karmane ||

(Parameshti PrajApati, Ushnik, SAkhA-Vatsa-Go )

**SAmaveda:**

> Agna AyAhi vitaye grihAno havyadAtaye nihoto satsi varhishi ||

(Gowtama, GAyatri, Agni)

**Atharva Veda:**

> Shanno devirabhishtaye Apo bhavantu pitaye sanyor bhisravantu nah ||

(I know only the Chandah for this Mantra and which is GAyatri)

Comment: Thanks once again Rickross. My intention was for Brahma Yajna and I have read somewhere the following text;

Comment: Brahma Yajna: This is accomplished if one studies the four Vedas. However the tradition has arisen that one recites the first four verses of each Veda after the noon sandhya as brahma yajna, whether one actually studies the Vedas or not. Please throw some light.

Comment: Ok @Yogyakartha So i guessed it right.. "Whether one studied the Vedas or not" not sure but in the Brahma Yajna the first mantras of the 4 Vedas are recited as per tradition.. It would be good if they have studied the Vedas entirely.. or  they should memorise the 4 first mantras at least..

Comment: Could you also post the chanting link please if available, especially for first verse of samaveda?

Comment: @VamsiEmani Hi I don't hv any online link ready at the moment .. I hv books which hv those Mantras.. We need to do a search .. You can also try doing the same ..